# How should I define a user's email in the model?

Tags: ruby, camping

I have a toy webapp in which my users' username is also their e-mail address (in a typical "`<username>@<host>`" format). I'm trying to make a method to calculate the user's e-mail address in the model as `User#email`, but I need access to the `URL()` helper method to do this, which isn't available in the Models module.

**Is there a way to access the root path the webapp has been bound to, from inside models?**

Answer (score 0):

`URL()` uses the request to figure out the host, but your models should be usable outside of a request too (e.g. in the console). In this case I recommend just storing it globally somewhere:

```
module App
  EMAIL_HOST = "hello.com"
end

module App::Models
  class User
    def email
      "#{username}@#{App::EMAIL_HOST}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there some way to "divine" the root through another layer, such as Rack, then? I tried to use ENV, but it isn't made available to models either.

Comment: Not really. If the email-address is dependent on the request, then it doesn't belong in the model. Create a helper instead.